# Detecting the empty PagedList result in Android

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-paging, android-paging-library

I am using the [Paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) library from Android Jetpack to have a paged loading behavior in my RecyclerView. Now I want a simple thing - get a signal in my UI that there is no data and the list is empty, so that I can show a message like "there are no items".

The problem is that I'm using `PositionalDataSource` **without placeholders** since I have no idea how big the list will be. Another problem is that I can only take the loaded items from the `PagedList` so I have no idea if more data is being currently loaded from my `DataSource`.

So the question is - does the `PagedList` or `DataSource` give out a signal like "i'm done loading"? That event is clearly defined in the library, since it will stop loading once it gets less data than asked, as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PositionalDataSource.LoadRangeParams#loadsize): *Returned data must be of this size, unless at end of the list*. The question is - **can I get that event signaled to me somehow?**

**For now I see the following solution**. I have implemented my `DataSource.Factory` just like in the Android Guide shows in [this page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/data#custom-data-source): giving out my `DataSource` as a `LiveData` in factory. Besides, I already exposed a `LiveData` object from `DataSource` called `isLoading`, I use it in the UI to show a progress bar every time `DataSource` loads something. I'm thinking to add another `LiveData` called `emptyResults` and then I can wire both together in my UI so that I will show my "no items" message when `emptyResults && !isLoading`.

I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me:

Add an adapter observer:

```
adapter?.registerAdapterDataObserver(adapterObserver)
```

Detect if the list is empty and 0 items are inserted

```
private val adapterObserver = object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {

        val count = adapter?.itemCount
        if (itemCount == 0 && count == 0) {
            // List is empty
        } else {
            // List is not empty
        }
    }
}
```